# Showing a custom Toast positioned into ListView Item position

Tags: android, listview, adapter, toast

I'm trying to show a custom toast exactly into deleted ListView item position. This is all I could do:

Adapter:

```
private View.OnClickListener onDeleteListener(final int position, final ViewHolder holder) {
        return new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showCustomToast(position, position);
            }
        };
    }

public void showCustomToast(int positionX, int positionY) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast_layout, null, false);
        ImageView icon = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.toast_image);
        TextView message = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.toast_text);
        LinearLayout fundoMensagem = (LinearLayout) layout.findViewById(R.id.toast_root);
        message.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        fundoMensagem.setBackgroundResource(R.color.error_colors);

        message.setText("Item Deleted!");
        Toast toast = new Toast(context);
        toast.setDuration(toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.setView(layout);
        toast.setGravity(positionX, positionX, positionX);
        toast.show();
    }
```

But this isn't exactly what I need because the **position** variable of the **onDeleteListener** method only get the item index and not the screen position. Someone can help me to show the custom toast at the center of each listview item?

Comment: Why you don't use RecyclerView ?

Comment: Hello @EdgarKhimich. How to?

Comment: use RecyclerView. It reusing already created views that save your memory from view creating process.  https://android.jlelse.eu/recyclerview-listview-basic-comparison-91e844a2fbc4

Comment: Using ListVIew its a bad practice. Read that link that I attached above

Answer (score 0):

You could use View.getLocationOnScreen() and/or getLocationInWindow() to get the absolute coordinates of a view on the screen, but I don't think a Toast is the right things to be putting there,  Toasts are system level notifications, not app level, so it would be a bit of a stretch to try to force it into a position in your app.  I think you would be much better served by some sort of custom view.

Comment: Ok. Could you help me with personalized vision?